# Yii framework creating and validating form input fields

Tags: php, validation, yii

I want to use HTML5 form inputs in my Yii project.

In the Yii framework, there are no functions to create `type ='email'` and `type='tel'` input fields like `type='text'`. There is a function to create text fields called `textField()` in the Yii Framework, but once I searched, they have only the `tag()` function to create "email" and "tel" input tags. I used that function in my code and created input fields, but the problem is that I cannot validate my form fields as it does so well with `textField()` functions.

This is my code:

```
echo CHtml::tag($tagName,
    array('id'=>'Contactus_email',
        'name'=>'Contactus['.$value['fieldname'].']',
        'class'=>'input_height',
        'type'=>'email',
        'placeholder'=>$value['placeholder']
    ), false, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

As there is no `CHtml::activeTag()` method, which theorically would bind your input to a `CActiveRecord` property, I think you can't do validation on that input using built-in framework classes.

However, you can [create your own](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/28979-how-to-override-yii-core-classes/) `CHtml` and add a method `MyHtml::activeEmailField()`, which would be basically the same than `CHtml::activeTextField()` but overwritting the `type=text` attribute to `type=email`.

At a server-side level, make sure that you are using [`CEmailValidator`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CEmailValidator) in your model rules to prevent undesired input.

Comment: Thanks..This answer could guide me to find the solution that I wanted. I think overwritting the CHtml::activeTextField() method in our own class doesn't need to do here. Because we can use the CHtml::activeEmailField() function instead of that. Go and see this link this could be helpful for you www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#activeEmailField-detail.

Comment: Awesome! I didn't know about `activeEmailField()` :)

Answer (score 0):

for same you have to define validation rule for email and tel in Yii and need to attach it to thease field in model rules section.